# Issue in calculating mean between two dates using a column in R

Tags: r, date, range, mean

I need to calculate the mean of a column based on two dates. The data table is shown below.

```
pol      id   acres    date           mean       st_date        end_date
12345    5    123.8    05_26_2019     0.2225     2019-07-24     2019-09-07
12345    5    123.8    06_11_2019     0.6523     2019-07-24     2019-09-07     
12345    5    123.8    06_27_2019     0.8563     2019-07-24     2019-09-07
12345    5    123.8    07_13_2019     0.1542     2019-07-24     2019-09-07
12345    5    123.8    07_29_2019     0.4253     2019-07-24     2019-09-07
12345    5    123.8    09_15_2019     0.1521     2019-07-24     2019-09-07
67890    4    60.0     05_05_2019     0.3652     2019-07-15     2019-08-31
67890    4    60.0     06_02_2019     0.4585     2019-07-15     2019-08-31
67890    4    60.0     07_10_2019     0.5856     2019-07-15     2019-08-31
67890    4    60.0     07_18_2019     0.6585     2019-07-15     2019-08-31
67890    4    60.0     09_02_2019     0.8585     2019-07-15     2019-08-31
```

I need to obtain the average of the mean column for the dates in date column falls between the st_date and end_date. Desired output is shown below. avg. column the average of mean column values of dates in date column falls between the st_date and end_date. (0.4253 + 0.1521)/2 = 0.2887

```
Output:

    pol      id   acres    date           mean       st_date        end_date       avg.
    12345    5    123.8    05_26_2019     0.2225     2019-07-24     2019-09-16     0.2887
    12345    5    123.8    06_11_2019     0.6523     2019-07-24     2019-09-16     0.2887
    12345    5    123.8    06_27_2019     0.8563     2019-07-24     2019-09-16     0.2887
    12345    5    123.8    07_13_2019     0.1542     2019-07-24     2019-09-16     0.2887
    12345    5    123.8    07_29_2019     0.4253     2019-07-24     2019-09-16     0.2887
    12345    5    123.8    09_15_2019     0.1521     2019-07-24     2019-09-16     0.2887
```

Can somebody help me to figure this out? I prefer the data.table solution.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you have multiple groups and you need calculate mean for each group. If that's the case please see if below code works for you:

```
> library(dplyr)
> library(tidyr)
> df %>% 
+ left_join(df %>% group_by(id) %>% filter(date> st_date & date < end_date) %>% mutate(avg = mean(mean)) %>% select(id, date, avg), by = c('id' = 'id', 'date' = 'date'), keep = F) %>% mutate(avg = replace_na(avg, mean(avg, na.rm = T)))
# A tibble: 6 x 8
    pol    id acres date        mean st_date    end_date     avg
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <date>     <dbl> <date>     <date>     <dbl>
1 12345     5  124. 2019-05-26 0.222 2019-07-24 2019-09-16 0.289
2 12345     5  124. 2019-06-11 0.652 2019-07-24 2019-09-16 0.289
3 12345     5  124. 2019-06-27 0.856 2019-07-24 2019-09-16 0.289
4 12345     5  124. 2019-07-13 0.154 2019-07-24 2019-09-16 0.289
5 12345     5  124. 2019-07-29 0.425 2019-07-24 2019-09-16 0.289
6 12345     5  124. 2019-09-15 0.152 2019-07-24 2019-09-16 0.289
>
```

My code:

```
final_pl_date_sel %>% 
  left_join(df %>% group_by(pol,id,acres) %>% filter(date> st_date & date < end_date) %>% mutate(avg = mean(mean)) %>% select(pol, id, acres, date, avg), by = c('pol' = 'pol','id' = 'id','acres' = 'acres', 'date' = 'date'), keep = F) %>% mutate(avg = replace_na(avg, mean(avg, na.rm = T)))
```

Using your code:

```
> df %>% 
+   left_join(df %>% group_by(pol, id, acres) %>% filter(date> st_date & date < end_date) %>% 
+       mutate(avg = mean(mean)) %>% select(pol, id, acres, date, avg), by = c('pol' = 'pol','id' = 'id','acres' = 'acres', 'date' = 'date'), keep = F) %>% 
+             mutate(avg = replace_na(avg, mean(avg, na.rm = T)))
# A tibble: 6 x 8
    pol    id acres date        mean st_date    end_date     avg
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <date>     <dbl> <date>     <date>     <dbl>
1 12345     5  124. 2019-05-26 0.222 2019-07-24 2019-09-16 0.289
2 12345     5  124. 2019-06-11 0.652 2019-07-24 2019-09-16 0.289
3 12345     5  124. 2019-06-27 0.856 2019-07-24 2019-09-16 0.289
4 12345     5  124. 2019-07-13 0.154 2019-07-24 2019-09-16 0.289
5 12345     5  124. 2019-07-29 0.425 2019-07-24 2019-09-16 0.289
6 12345     5  124. 2019-09-15 0.152 2019-07-24 2019-09-16 0.289
```

used "df" as left table as I don't have "final_pl_date_sel" table.

My df:

```
> df
# A tibble: 6 x 7
    pol    id acres date        mean st_date    end_date  
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <date>     <dbl> <date>     <date>    
1 12345     5  124. 2019-05-26 0.222 2019-07-24 2019-09-16
2 12345     5  124. 2019-06-11 0.652 2019-07-24 2019-09-16
3 12345     5  124. 2019-06-27 0.856 2019-07-24 2019-09-16
4 12345     5  124. 2019-07-13 0.154 2019-07-24 2019-09-16
5 12345     5  124. 2019-07-29 0.425 2019-07-24 2019-09-16
6 12345     5  124. 2019-09-15 0.152 2019-07-24 2019-09-16
>
```

Comment: This is what I want. Yes I have multiple groups. Do you know the data.table solution to this? Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have data.table solution, work mostly with tibble and tidyverse packages. As they also work with data.tables

Comment: When I tried above, I am getting this error "Error in tbl_vars(y) : argument "y" is missing, with no default". No idea why.

Comment: Can you please share what you are executing verbatim.

Comment: Actually when I tried i am getting a different answer. i need to group by pol, id and acres. How can i correct that?

Comment: It runs fine for me, please check my answer

Comment: can you please post your df?

Comment: Done, btw are all your date columns "date" datatype?

Comment: Let's continue in discussion chat. So have added my data, were you able to run using your own code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223300/discussion-between-nudu-and-karthik-s).